# First steps in python: how to combine two lists

Tags: python

So I just started learning a few basics with Python. Since I am a pretty practical person, I enjoy doing it with the book "Automate the boring stuff with Python".

No there is a chapter introducing lists in python and their advantages.
To be practical one should write a code which asks the user to enter cat names, which then will be added to the list. If no cat name is added anymore, all the cat names should be displayed.

Until now, fair enough. So I thought I should give it a try and go a small step further and extend the functionality by adding the ages of the cats. The desired result would be that the user is asked for the name input, then the age input, the name input again and the age input again and so on. If the user doesn´t put in a name again, it should list the cats with the respective ages.

I created a second list and also the second input and everything kinda works but I just dont know how to combine the both lists or rather the values.

It just gives me the two names first and then the two ages.

Is anyone happy to help me with this beginner problem?

Thanks in advance

```
catNames = []
catAges = []

while True:
    print("Enter the name of Cat " + str(len(catNames) + 1) + "(Or enter 
          nothing to stop.)")
    name = input()
    while name !="":
        print("Enter the age of cat ")
        age = input()
        break

    if name == "":
        print("The cat names and ages are: ")
        for name in catNames:
            print(" " + name)
        for age in catAges:
            print(" " + age)
        break
    catNames = catNames + [name]
    catAges = catAges + [age]
```

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is the output you are getting, and how does it differ from the output you desire?

Comment: tl;dr. Please try to get directly to the point

Comment: Actually the solution and outcome posted by AronC shows perfectly my desired outcome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you would use [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for this kind of task.

But if you were to use lists for your problem, it could be implemented like this:

```
catNames = []
catAges = []

while True:
    print("Enter the name of Cat " + str(len(catNames) + 1) + "(Or enter nothing to stop.)")
    name = input()
    while name !="":
        print("Enter the age of cat ")
        age = input()
        break

    if name == "":
        print("The cat names and ages are: ")
        for i in range(len(catNames)):
            print("Cat number",i, "has the name", catNames[i], "and is", catAges[i], "years old")
        break

    catNames = catNames + [name]
    catAges = catAges + [age]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Basically I was looking for an alternative to the              
 "for name in catNames"

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
catNames = ['Fluffy', 'Whiskers', 'Bob']
catAges = [5, 18, 2]
catZip = zip(catNames, catAges)
print(list(catZip))
```

Out:

```
[('Fluffy', 5), ('Whiskers', 18), ('Bob', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I can understand correctly you want it to print the age and the name together?
Well if thats so you can do it like this:

```
catNames = []
catAges = []

while True:
    name = input("Enter the name of Cat {} (Or enter nothing to stop): ".format(str(len(catNames) + 1)))
    while name != "":
        age = input("Enter the age of {}: ".format(name)) # Takes inputted name and adds it to the print function.
        catNames.append(name) # Adds the newest name the end of the catNames list.
        catAges.append(age) # Adds the newest age the end of the catNames list.
        break

    if name == "":
        print("\nThe cat names and ages are: ")
        for n in range(len(catNames)):
            print("\nName: {}\nAge: {}".format(catNames[n], catAges[n]))
        break
```

Resulting output:

```
Enter the name of Cat 1 (Or enter nothing to stop): Cat1
Enter the age of Cat1: 5
Enter the name of Cat 2 (Or enter nothing to stop): Cat2
Enter the age of Cat2: 7
Enter the name of Cat 3 (Or enter nothing to stop): # I hit enter here so it skips.

The cat names and ages are: 

Name: Cat1
Age: 5

Name: Cat2
Age: 7
```

If you have any issues with what I did, please just ask.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!